# Why does Windows lock when editing an open file, when Linux doesn't?

Tags: windows, linux, filesystems

If I'm writing a `LaTeX` file in linux I can recompile and the changes just 'appear' on the open PDF. If I use a bash script to edit a .txt file, I get the option reload it.

Not so in windows, which seems to prefer blocking my actions until the file is closed.

Why are the two so different? Is this a failing of the file system (I've not tried this in Linux on NTFS or FAT32, only ever one of the ext FSs)? Or is it something different?

Comment: What PDF viewer you are using in Linux? And what in Windows?

Comment: Uh, I don't know. The standard one for ubuntu?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the specific software @Serge, but with how Linux deals with files. For example, you can also start watching a video while it is downloading in Linux.

Comment: No, no, it is relevant. The OP asks why do I see the updates and why they are possible at all

Comment: @Serge are you implying that it wouldn't work if I used a 'windows' program? But then, that's a program built to work on windows. That makes me think that no windows program can update in this way, and I'm back to "Why does windows lock...?"

Comment: It *does* depend on the specific software, @terdon. A Windows program can open files in several "share" modes, one of which allows other programs to read the open file, another allwos read and write.

Comment: Also, @Pureferret, it is up to the specific software to implement file change monitoring as well. Evince in Linux does this; Adobe Reader in Windows doesn't bother to and just disallows modifications instead.

Comment: Then why does it seem most windows programs 'don't bother'?

Comment: I was just referring to the lack of file locking in general in Linux systems. You don't get the "This file is in use by another program" error in Linux the way you do in windows.

Comment: Because it simplifies the programmer's task

Comment: The "share modes" might be a relic from the MS-DOS days, now that I think of it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What PDF viewer you are using in Linux? And what in Windows?
>
> Uh, I don't know. The standard one for ubuntu?

This is the answer. It's the implementation defined behavior. It is completely feasible in Windows to design a viewer that will not lock the file from writing by other processes<sup>1</sup> and monitor the original file for possible changes<sup>2</sup> and prompt you if such changes occurs.

However, you may read [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49299/what-is-linux-doing-differently-that-allows-me-to-remove-replace-files-where-win/49306#49306) to get an overview on how files are usualy managed in *nix like systems.

---

<sup>1</sup> The programmer could specify *dwShareMode=FILE_SHARE_WRITE* when calling [CreateFile()](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49299/what-is-linux-doing-differently-that-allows-me-to-remove-replace-files-where-win/49306#49306).

<sup>2</sup> [FindFirstChangeNotification()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows, inotify on Linux

Comment: Then why not design one?

Comment: There are a few valuable technical reason's to make a non-friendly (in context of this post) viewer. The viewer implemented, exist, and satisfies the needs of the majority of users. Who will pay for designing another viewer?

Comment: Not only are there plenty of *free* file viewers or various kinds, they exist on linux already. I don't think that argument of "If it's not broken, then why re-invent the wheel." doesn't seem to hold.

Comment: Yes, I do not argue. The problem is that there should be some one with  a will to do it himself or to pay for it.